# TF: Conner tensor of horizontally stacked images to video (3D to 4D)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently loading a dataset in tensor flow which consists of small video sequences (about 30 frames) instead of `GIF/MPEG` they provide them in `JPEG` format. One Image consists of 20-30 frames stacked horizontally.

Now I am loading the image with TF using `tf.image.decode_jpeg`. 
The width of the image is 64 pixels (fixed) and the hight is 64*number_of_frames so the overall shape is `(64*number_of_frames,64,3)`.

Is there any nice way to convert this into a `(number_of_frames,64,64,3)` tensor?

Followup: Also I would like to repeat the last frame if the video is too short such that all samples have the same number of frames resulting in a `(some_const,64,64,3)` tensor.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the first 64 in the shape of the tensor is height since tensorflow reads the image as a tensor which is `(H, W, C)` or height, width, channels respectively

Comment: So, your interpretation of "hight is 64*number_of_frames" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
tf.transpose(tf.reshape(input, [64, 64, number_of_frames, 3]), perm=[2, 0, 1, 3]))
```

would work. I nest two things: first break down the second dimension, into two dimensions of size 64 and number_of_frames, and then I permute the dimensions to match the `(64,64*number_of_frames,3)` ordering.

Caveat: Depending on how your data is organized, you may want to change `[64, 64, number_of_frames, 3]` to `[64, number_of_frames, 64, 3]` and `[2, 0, 1, 3]` to `[1, 0, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.transpose and tf.reshape like this way,

```
tf.reshape(tf.transpose(x, perm=[1, 0, 2]), [-1, 64, 64, 3])
```

Comment: Please add more context. What does this code do and how does it work?